# Dynamic array of names where it loops through a dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I have code below that does the following

1. Goes through column a and creates an array for all unique names found.
2. Loops through the array, creates a worksheet, and copies the data over with the matching array name.

I want to modify the code where instead of creating an array based off of column A, it gets created by a separate worksheet of current employees on the team. The worksheet will be called "employees". The employee list can change day to day.

1. If employee name is found, create worksheet and copy records to it.
2. If employee is not found based on array, initialize a worksheet called 'UNMONITORED' and copy the records to this spreadsheet

VBA code

```
Sub SeparateData()
 
    Dim wsAllData As Worksheet
    Dim arrFiltCol() As Variant
    Dim arrUnique() As Variant
    Dim arrElement As Variant
    Dim wsIndivData As Worksheet
    Dim rngFiltVisible As Range
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    Set wsAllData = Worksheets("query_export_results")
     
    With wsAllData
        'Using Transpose avoids necessity of referencing array elements as 2 dimensional.
        'arrFiltCol() = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))    'If two rows of headers
        arrFiltCol() = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)))    'If one row of headers
    End With
     
    arrUnique() = UniqueArray(arrFiltCol())
     
    'Following loop creates any worksheets that do not currently exist.
    For Each arrElement In arrUnique()
        Set wsIndivData = Nothing   'Initialize to Nothing or previous setting is retained
         
        On Error Resume Next
        'Next line errors if worksheet does not exist (Hense, previous line)
        Set wsIndivData = Worksheets(arrElement)
        On Error GoTo 0     'Resume error trapping ASAP.
         
        If wsIndivData Is Nothing Then  'If Is Nothing then sheet does not exist
            'Next 2 lines: Add worksheet and name as per array element
            Set wsIndivData = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            wsIndivData.Name = arrElement
             
            'Next 2 lines: Copy column headers from master sheet and set font to Bold
            wsIndivData.Rows("1:2").Value = wsAllData.Rows("1:2").Value
            wsIndivData.Rows("1:2").Font.Bold = True
        Else
            'Next code: Clear any existing data below column headers
            With wsIndivData
                '.Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).EntireRow.ClearContents  'If two rows of headers
                .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).EntireRow.ClearContents  'If one row of headers
            End With
        End If
         
    Next arrElement
     
    With wsAllData
        .AutoFilterMode = False 'This command turns off AutoFilter if AutoFilter is on
        '.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).AutoFilter    'If two rows of headers
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).AutoFilter    'If one row of headers
    End With
     
    With wsAllData.AutoFilter.Range
        For Each arrElement In arrUnique()
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arrElement
            Set rngFiltVisible = .Offset(1, 0) _
                                    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
                                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             
            rngFiltVisible.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(arrElement).Cells(3, 1)
            Worksheets(arrElement).Columns.AutoFit
            Application.Goto Worksheets(arrElement).Cells(1, 1) 'Clear full selection
        Next arrElement
    End With
     
    wsAllData.ShowAllData
    Application.Goto wsAllData.Cells(1, 1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     
    MsgBox "Finished"
         
End Sub

Function UniqueArray(MyArray As Variant) As Variant
    
    Dim arrTemp()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim varTemp
    Dim k As Long
     
    'Bubble Sort the array
    For j = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) - 1
        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) - 1
            If MyArray(i) > MyArray(i + 1) Then
                varTemp = MyArray(i)
                MyArray(i) = MyArray(i + 1)
                MyArray(i + 1) = varTemp
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
     
    'Following code: Removes multiple occurrences of the name.
    k = 1   'Initialize for first element in the unique array
    ReDim arrTemp(1 To k)   'Initialize to One element or ReDim Preserve fails with earlier versions of Excel
     
    For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) - 1
        If MyArray(i) <> MyArray(i + 1) Then    'Not equal to previous then copy to new array
            ReDim Preserve arrTemp(1 To k)  'Does not increment on first iteration because k has not increased
            arrTemp(k) = MyArray(i)         'Copy element not equal to next element in array
            k = k + 1   'Increment ready for next ReDim Preserve
        End If
    Next i
     
    ReDim Preserve arrTemp(1 To k)  'Ready for Last element of array
    arrTemp(k) = MyArray(i)         'Last element of array (Loop above only processes to 2nd last element)
     
    UniqueArray = arrTemp() 'Assign the temporary array to the Function array.
     
End Function
```

Dynamic Array and Raw Dataset

[image]

[image]

Comment: `wsIndivData.Rows("1:2").Value = wsAllData.Rows("1:2").Value` is copying 2 rows of headers. `Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, 1)` suggests only 1 header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SeparateData2()
    Const QRY_HDR = 2 ' query sheet header
    Const EMP_HDR = 1 ' employees sheet header
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dictEmp As Object, dictWs As Object, s As String, k
    Dim r As Long, lastrow As Long, t0 As Single, msg As String
    t0 = Timer
    
    Set dictEmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictWs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   
    ' create dictionary of names
    With wb.Sheets("employees")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = EMP_HDR + 1 To lastrow
            s = Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
            If Len(s) > 0 Then dictEmp(s) = r
        Next
    End With
    
    ' check existing sheets, clear if on employees list
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        dictWs.Add ws.Name, Nothing ' will hold copy source ranges
        If dictEmp.exists(ws.Name) Then
            ws.Rows(QRY_HDR + 1).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - QRY_HDR).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    
    ' build copy ranges for each employee or UNMONITORED
    With wb.Sheets("query_export_results")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = QRY_HDR + 1 To lastrow
            s = Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
            'is this an employee
            If Not dictEmp.exists(s) Then
                s = "UNMONITORED"
            End If
              
            ' create sheet if not exist
            If Not dictWs.exists(s) Then
                Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
                ws.Name = s
                msg = msg & vbLf & s
                ' copy QRY_HDR
                .Rows(1).Resize(QRY_HDR).Copy ws.Cells(1, 1)
                dictWs.Add s, Nothing
            End If
              
            ' build copy range
            If dictWs(s) Is Nothing Then
                Set dictWs(s) = .Rows(r)
            Else
                Set dictWs(s) = Application.Union(dictWs(s), .Rows(r))
            End If
    
         Next
    End With
   
    ' copy rows
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each k In dictWs
        If Not dictWs(k) Is Nothing Then
            dictWs(k).Copy wb.Sheets(k).Cells(QRY_HDR + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
    If msg = "" Then msg = "None"
    MsgBox lastrow - QRY_HDR & " rows scanned" & vbLf & _
           "sheets created: " & msg, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
```